# GROUP BY and ORDER

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb, sql-order-by

I have a very simple Maria DB for home automation purpose. This is the essential extract of my ER:

[image]

`TelldusActionsPerformed` is a log table. It is used for keeping track of very different actions (like a temperature measurements, a door closing, a power switch turned etc) performed at different times.

I use the following query to fetch interesting data:

```
SELECT
    TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime AS TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
    TelldusUnits.Name AS TelldusUnits_Name,
    TelldusActionValues.ActionValue AS TelldusActionValues_ActionValue,
    TelldusActionValueTypes.Name AS TelldusActionValueTypes_Name
FROM
    TelldusActions
    INNER JOIN TelldusUnits ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusUnit_Id = TelldusUnits.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionTypes ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionType_Id = TelldusActionTypes.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValues ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionValue_Id = TelldusActionValues.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValueTypes ON TelldusActionValues.FK_TelldusActionValueType_Id = TelldusActionValueTypes.Id 
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionsPerformed ON TelldusActionsPerformed.FK_TelldusAction_Id = TelldusActions.Id
    WHERE TelldusUnits.Name IN ("Grovkök golvtermostat", "Huvudtermostat", "Uterum golvtermostat")
AND TelldusActionValueTypes.Name IN ("watt","temp")
ORDER BY TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime DESC
```

This gives me a result set which looks like this
[image]

I would like to refine my query to only return the absolutely latest (time) unique combinations for the `TelldusUnits.Name` + `TelldusActionValueTypes.Name` fields:
[image]

I believe that I need to `GROUP BY TelldusUnits.Name, TelldusActionValueTypes.Name` to get the unique combinations? Is it possible to limit my search result to the latest unique combinations for the `TelldusUnits.Name` + `TelldusActionValueTypes.Name` fields with SQL only? How?

## Edit 1:

If I run mr Murillo's script right out of the box (I only added FROM_UNIXTIME(), forgot it in my original question):

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime)) AS TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
    TelldusUnits.Name AS TelldusUnits_Name,
    TelldusActionValues.ActionValue AS TelldusActionValues_ActionValue,
    TelldusActionValueTypes.Name AS TelldusActionValueTypes_Name
FROM
    TelldusActions
    INNER JOIN TelldusUnits ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusUnit_Id = TelldusUnits.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionTypes ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionType_Id = TelldusActionTypes.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValues ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionValue_Id = TelldusActionValues.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValueTypes ON TelldusActionValues.FK_TelldusActionValueType_Id = TelldusActionValueTypes.Id 
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionsPerformed ON TelldusActionsPerformed.FK_TelldusAction_Id = TelldusActions.Id
    WHERE TelldusUnits.Name IN ("Grovkök golvtermostat", "Huvudtermostat", "Uterum golvtermostat")
AND TelldusActionValueTypes.Name IN ("watt","temp")
GROUP BY TelldusUnits.Name, TelldusActionValues.ActionValue, TelldusActionValueTypes.Name
ORDER BY TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime DESC
```

I get the following result set:
[image]

The `ORDER BY TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime DESC` confuses me. The table does not seem to be ordered descendant according to `PerformedTime`?
(`PerformedTime`, UNIX-timestamp is of datatype int(11) )

## Edit 2:

The next update regarding to mr Murillo's commnt gave me a better sort:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime)) AS TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
    TelldusUnits.Name AS TelldusUnits_Name,
    TelldusActionValues.ActionValue AS TelldusActionValues_ActionValue,
    TelldusActionValueTypes.Name AS TelldusActionValueTypes_Name

FROM
    TelldusActions
    INNER JOIN TelldusUnits ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusUnit_Id = TelldusUnits.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionTypes ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionType_Id = TelldusActionTypes.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValues ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionValue_Id = TelldusActionValues.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValueTypes ON TelldusActionValues.FK_TelldusActionValueType_Id = TelldusActionValueTypes.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionsPerformed ON TelldusActionsPerformed.FK_TelldusAction_Id = TelldusActions.Id
WHERE TelldusUnits.Name IN ("Grovkök golvtermostat", "Huvudtermostat", "Uterum golvtermostat")
AND TelldusActionValueTypes.Name IN ("watt","temp")
GROUP BY TelldusUnits.Name, TelldusActionValues.ActionValue, TelldusActionValueTypes.Name
ORDER BY MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime) DESC
```

[image]

There still is a detail to take care of (according to my original question: I only wanted the query to return the absolutely latest (time) unique combinations for the `TelldusUnits.Name` + `TelldusActionValueTypes.Name` fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're Right, if you want the latest time, you'll need to add a GROUP BY clause not considering TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime. Please try this script

```
SELECT
    --TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime AS TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
    MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime) AS TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
    TelldusUnits.Name AS TelldusUnits_Name,
    TelldusActionValues.ActionValue AS TelldusActionValues_ActionValue,
    TelldusActionValueTypes.Name AS TelldusActionValueTypes_Name
FROM
    TelldusActions
    INNER JOIN TelldusUnits ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusUnit_Id = TelldusUnits.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionTypes ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionType_Id = TelldusActionTypes.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValues ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionValue_Id = TelldusActionValues.Id
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionValueTypes ON TelldusActionValues.FK_TelldusActionValueType_Id = TelldusActionValueTypes.Id 
    INNER JOIN TelldusActionsPerformed ON TelldusActionsPerformed.FK_TelldusAction_Id = TelldusActions.Id
    WHERE TelldusUnits.Name IN ("Grovkök golvtermostat", "Huvudtermostat", "Uterum golvtermostat")
AND TelldusActionValueTypes.Name IN ("watt","temp")
GROUP BY TelldusUnits.Name,TelldusActionValues.ActionValue,TelldusActionValueTypes.Name
ORDER BY TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get a strange (?) behavior with the `ORDER BY` clause. It does not seem to be taken account?

Comment: Oh sure, I forgot to add MAX at the end... ORDER BY MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime)  DESC, it should work, greetings

Answer (score 0):

## The working answer

I was really helped by Murillos answer even though it did not completely answered my question (I still consider it is a good answer). This is the query I finally used and (hopefully) answers my original question:

```
SELECT 
    OrderedResultSet.TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
    OrderedResultSet.TelldusUnits_Name,
    OrderedResultSet.TelldusActionValues_ActionValue,
    OrderedResultSet.TelldusActionValueTypes_Name

FROM (
    SELECT
        FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime)) AS TelldusActionsPerformed_PerformedTime,
        TelldusUnits.Name AS TelldusUnits_Name,
        TelldusActionValues.ActionValue AS TelldusActionValues_ActionValue,
        TelldusActionValueTypes.Name AS TelldusActionValueTypes_Name

    FROM
        TelldusActions
        INNER JOIN TelldusUnits ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusUnit_Id = TelldusUnits.Id
        INNER JOIN TelldusActionTypes ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionType_Id = TelldusActionTypes.Id
        INNER JOIN TelldusActionValues ON TelldusActions.FK_TelldusActionValue_Id = TelldusActionValues.Id
        INNER JOIN TelldusActionValueTypes ON TelldusActionValues.FK_TelldusActionValueType_Id = TelldusActionValueTypes.Id
        INNER JOIN TelldusActionsPerformed ON TelldusActionsPerformed.FK_TelldusAction_Id = TelldusActions.Id

    WHERE TelldusUnits.Name IN ("Grovkök golvtermostat", "Huvudtermostat", "Uterum golvtermostat")
        AND TelldusActionValueTypes.Name IN ("watt","temp")

    GROUP BY TelldusUnits.Name, TelldusActionValues.ActionValue, TelldusActionValueTypes.Name

    ORDER BY MAX(TelldusActionsPerformed.PerformedTime) DESC
) as OrderedResultSet

GROUP BY OrderedResultSet.TelldusUnits_Name, OrderedResultSet.TelldusActionValueTypes_Name
```

This gives me the top results (latest time):
[image]